# Python with XPATH: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying to use 'count', an XPATH function, to count the number of child nodes a HTML element has.

```
elements = request.html.xpath('//*[@class="some class"]')
for e in elements:
    print(e.xpath('count(*)')
```

I am using the Requests-HTML library, so each `e` in `elements` is an `Element` class instance.

However, when I run the code above, an error is received:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

extended code:

```
from requests_html import HTML
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.python.org/')
element = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="about"]')
for e in element:
    print(e.xpath('count(*)'))
```

Comment: Syntax error in what way? It returns all the elements that have a specified class.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had made that mistake when writing the code here, but is correct in the actual code.

Comment: I suggest you make an [mcve] so that it's actually possible to copy your code and reproduce your issue.

Comment: I added an extended code, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the count of children. Without having read the source code of `requests_html`, here is my best guess of what happens.

- The expression `count(*)` gets evaluated. It returns a number.
- The `.xpath()` method tries to return a *list* of matching nodes.
- It unconditionally tries to iterate the XPath result to build that list, leading to `'float' object is not iterable`. This is probably a bug.

Work-around

```
from requests_html import HTML
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.python.org/')
element = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="about"]')
for e in element:
    print(len(e.xpath('*')))
```

Similarly, errors also occur for expressions such as `string(*)` or `normalize-space(*)`.